# Pull out all transactions after a bad credit found

Tags: sql, r, spss

Below is a small dataset of transaction records, with ID, DATE of the month, dummy variable of Bad_Credit or not. I would like to pull out all the transactions after a bad credit start.
The OUTPUT column indicate the correct result, which is row 1,2,3,5,6,8,10.

This is just an example, there could be thousands of rows. SQL, R, SPSS will all work. Thank you.

| DATE | ID | Bad_CREDIT | OUTPUT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | A | 1 | 1 |
| 15 | A | 1 | 1 |
| 18 | A | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | B | 0 | 0 |
| 10 | B | 1 | 1 |
| 20 | B | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | C | 0 | 0 |
| 15 | C | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | D | 0 | 0 |
| 9 | E | 1 | 1 |

Comment: BTW, bad credit doesn't have to be from the second transaction, it could be third or later...

Comment: Anyone know how to use SPSS to make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(case when bad_credit = 1 then date end) over (partition by id) as min_bd_date
      from t
     ) t
where date >= min_bd_date;
```

You can also do this with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date >= (select min(t2.date)
                 from t t2
                 where t2.id = t.id and
                       t2.bad_credit = 1
                );
```

Comment: Thank you. Works great.

Comment: @GanRen . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted the answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can `arrange` the data by `ID` and `DATE` and for each `ID` assign 0 if the first value of `Bad_CREDIT` is 0.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(ID, DATE) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(OUTPUT = as.integer(!(first(Bad_CREDIT) == 0 & row_number() == 1)))

#    DATE ID    Bad_CREDIT OUTPUT
#   <int> <chr>      <int>  <int>
# 1    12 A              1      1
# 2    15 A              1      1
# 3    18 A              0      1
# 4     2 B              0      0
# 5    10 B              1      1
# 6    20 B              0      1
# 7     5 C              0      0
# 8    15 C              1      1
# 9     1 D              0      0
#10     9 E              1      1
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(DATE = c(12L, 15L, 18L, 2L, 10L, 20L, 5L, 15L, 
1L, 9L), ID = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", 
"E"), Bad_CREDIT = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L)), 
row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm not good at dplyr, only use sqldf :)

Answer (score 1):

If this is in a database, then I think SQL is likely the better place to address this. However, if you already have it in R, then ...

Here's an R method, using `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(OUTPUT2 = +cumany(Bad_CREDIT)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 10 x 5
#     DATE ID    Bad_CREDIT OUTPUT OUTPUT2
#    <int> <chr>      <int>  <int>   <int>
#  1    12 A              1      1       1
#  2    15 A              1      1       1
#  3    18 A              0      1       1
#  4     2 B              0      0       0
#  5    10 B              1      1       1
#  6    20 B              0      1       1
#  7     5 C              0      0       0
#  8    15 C              1      1       1
#  9     1 D              0      0       0
# 10     9 E              1      1       1
```

Because this is effectively a simple grouping operation, then base R and `data.table` solutions are as straight-forward.

```r
+ave(dat$Bad_CREDIT, dat$ID, FUN=cumany)
#  [1] 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1

library(data.table)
datDT <- as.data.table(dat)
datDT[, OUTPUT2 := +cumany(Bad_CREDIT), by = .(ID)]
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm not good at dplyr, only use sqldf :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EXISTS` as follows:

```
select t.* from your_table t
where exists
     (select 1
        from your_table tt
       where t.id = tt.id
         and t.date >= tt.date 
         and tt.bad_credit = 1);
```

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

This is for SPSS:

```
sort cases by ID date.
compute PullOut=Bad_CREDIT.
if $casenum>1 and ID=lag(ID) and lag(PullOut)=1 PullOut=1.
exe.
```